# Password protect a domain

Tags: html, css, passwords

I am currently making a little forum type site for me and some others, but I wanted to know how I could be able to password protect it, and make sure that nobody can access the pages within the site by changing the URL.

I have made a box where you put the password, and a button, but I wanted to know how I can make the input validate against the real password and then allow/disallow the person from accessing the pages.

```
    <input id="password" type="password">
    <p id="enter"><a class="link" href="#">Enter</a></p>
```

There's the markup, and the CSS is nothing special, just styling it. If anyone can help me that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

The HTML code you wrote (this includes the CSS) gets sent to the browser of a visitor. This is also true for any JavaScript you include in your webpage because JavaScript is run locally inside a clients browser. Thus it's not advisable to use any of these to build a login system. You will definitely need some kind of *backend*. You need at least a database of some kind, that is stored on the webserver, inside a directory, that can't be accessed from outside to store the different user-name/password combinations, and a script/program that runs **on the server** (not in the browser of a visitor) that compares the user-name/password submitted to the database.
I'd suggest to use a framework (e.g. Django, NodeJS, etc.) that provides said funtionality out-of-the-box. I strongly discourage writing code like this yourself.